# bash/terminal RH remove last 3 characters of filename

Tags: bash, shell, redhat

I have thousands of images in a folder and subdirectories, I tried to create a compress file of them all. Somehow I have inadvertently added .gz to the end of every image.

```
image1.jpg.gz
image2.jpg.gz
/Folder/image3.jpg.gz
```

Im trying to find the correct command to remove all of the .gz extension and keep the .jpg extension.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work probably.

```
find . -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c 'mv "${1%%.gz}"{.gz,}' - {} \;
```

Comment: this didn't fix my problem but acheived what i asked. they actually needed extracting as they were compressed so had to use gunzip *.gz

Comment: @Philwn ah I was wondering why you would have just added gz to them all... Glad it's sorted!